# I'm getting a NotImplementedException when trying to call a Reporting Services Web Method

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

I am trying to call the GetReportParameters method from the ReportingServices2005.asmx web service from another C# function and I am getting the following error:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

I litterally just copied the code from Microsoft's site here:

[Get Parameters Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsmanagementservice2005.reportingservice2005.getreportparameters%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

which is this code:

```
            bool forRendering = false;
            string historyID = null;
            ParameterValue[] values = null;
            DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
            ReportParameter[] parameters = null;

            try
            {
                parameters = rs.GetReportParameters(reportName,historyID, forRendering, values,credentials);

                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (ReportParameter rp in parameters)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", rp.Name);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (SoapException e)
            {
                error = e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString();
            }
```

Where `reportName` is a string with the name of the report.

Any ideas??

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here is the full stack trace:

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
at Foo.Foo.ReportingService2005.GetReportParameters(String reportName, String historyID, Boolean forRendering, ParameterValue[] values, DataSourceCredentials[] credentials) in C:\Visual Studio Projects\Foo\Foo\Web References\Foo\Reference.cs:line 4112
at Foo.Foo.GetReportParameters(String username, String password, String reportName) in C:\Visual Studio Projects\Foo\Foo\Foo.asmx.cs:line 265
```

Comment: can you add more of the stack trace to your question? Generally IME a NotImplementedException has to be explicitly thrown from a method whose body consists solely of `throw new NotImplementedException();`

Comment: I added the stack trace and it looks like its resonating from 'Resources.cs' .. I'm not even sure where that file is located in my project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted and re-added the Web Reference and this didn't do the trick, but after lots of trial and error I noticed that

```
ParameterValue[] values = null;
DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
ReportParameter[] parameters = null;
```

Were all referencing another Web Reference....  Not even sure how that's possible.. But, I deleted the other Web Reference that had nothing to do with Reporting Services and all is now working.